# Programa me devuelve 2 veces el mismo texto Impreso c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

de antemano gracias por venir a rescatarme y si la pregunta no esta bien formulada sean libres de editarlas xd

Este es codigo que tengo para el argumento

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if( argv = "--version"){
            cout << "a";
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Pero el programa me devuelme 2 veces el mismo texto imprimido

`aa`

¿A que se debe?

Comment: *Devuelve*,  no *devuelme*.  *Impreso*, no *imprimido*. Cuidemos la ortografía, gramática y redacción.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te devuelve dos veces porque argc cuenta la cantidad de palabras pasadas en la terminal, la cual incluye el propio nombre de la aplicación. Si tu aplicación se llama *app* y en la terminal ingresas 'app --version' el valor de argc es 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {   
        if( strcmp(argv[i], "--version") == 0 ){
            cout << "a";
        }
    }   
    return 0;

}
```